# Is there a way to get an exact match in a javascript filter

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to get an exact match in a javascript filter. I've been following the lessons [here at w3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp). When I search "1" now it still displays results for 1, 11 & 14. However I would like to only display 1 for 1, 11 for 11 etc... Is this possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>Dublin Transport History</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link href="w3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search Number..." title="Type in a Number" type="text">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th class="w3-center">A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th class="w3-center">F</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="w3-center">1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Boat</td>
            <td class="w3-center">House</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="w3-center">11</td>
            <td>Adam</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Pink</td>
            <td>Car</td>
            <td class="w3-center">Apartment</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="w3-center">14</td>
            <td>Nelson</td>
            <td>Tower</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Bicycle</td>
            <td class="w3-center">Cottage</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried a few different things but I am new to Javascript and can't really find a good solution.

Comment: Don't use `.indexOf()`, compare the whole strings.

Comment: Ditch w3 and head over to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript) for better return on your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter on the exact string, you need to change this :

```
txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
```

with this :

```
txtValue.toUpperCase() == filter
```

and make sure to do validation for that input. if `filter` is empty, then all data will be displayed. Try This :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>Dublin Transport History</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link href="w3.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search Number..." title="Type in a Number" type="text">
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr class="header">
            <th class="w3-center">A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th class="w3-center">F</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="w3-center">1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Boat</td>
            <td class="w3-center">House</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="w3-center">11</td>
            <td>Adam</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Pink</td>
            <td>Car</td>
            <td class="w3-center">Apartment</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td class="w3-center">14</td>
            <td>Nelson</td>
            <td>Tower</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>Bicycle</td>
            <td class="w3-center">Cottage</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if(filter) {
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase() == filter) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may compare the equality between `txtValue` and `filter` itself instead.

```js
if (txtValue.toUpperCase() === filter) {...}
```